# Use variable passed via include to set value of paramenter

Tags: templating, variable, include

I have an include setup for Navigation which works fine if I hard code in the level of the structure I want to use. However I need this to be set differently if the nav appears in the head or the footer.

head:

```
      {% include "_includes/nav"
        with {
          'listType' : 'list-inline pull-right',
          'navLevel'  : '2'
        }
      %}
```

footer:

```
      {% include "_includes/nav"
        with {
          'listType' : 'list-unstyled',
          'navLevel'  : '1'
        }
      %}
```

The include looks like this where I want the `.level('<=2')` to have the value passed via the include. However when I attempt this `.level('<=navLevel')` or similar the entire nav does not render.

```
{% set navigation %}

 {% set pages = craft.entries.section('navigation').level('<=2') %}

 <ul class="{{ listType }}">
   {% nav page in pages %}
     <li>
       {# Check for entry type / get related entry #}
       {% if page.type == 'internalLink' %}
           {% set linkedEntry = page.sitePageLink.limit(1).first() %}
           <a href="{{ linkedEntry.url }}"  data-url="{{ entry.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
       {% endif %}

       {# Check for entry type / get offsiteLinks #}
       {% if page.type == 'offsiteLink' %}
           <a href="{{ page.offSiteLink }}"  data-url="{{ entry.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
       {% endif %}

       {% ifchildren %}
         {# dropdown not set up yet #}
          <ul class="dropdown" style="background:pink">
              {% children %}
          </ul>
      {% endifchildren %}

     </li>
   {% endnav %}
 </ul>

 {% endset %}

 {# replace data-uri with active class #}
 {{ navigation|replace({('data-url="' ~ craft.request.getUrl() ~ '"'): 'class="active"'})|raw }}
```

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to concatenate the string you pass to the `level` parameter, using the `~` operator:

```
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('navigation').level('<='~navLevel) %}
```

Comment: Thanks Mats, didn't know about that. Still a noob at twig.